# Limits and colimits in the category of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, limits-colimits

What is the smallest category enlarging the category of schemes over a field $k$ which is:

1. Complete? Cocomplete?
2. Admits a cogenerator? generator?

I admit there is some overlap with my previous questions. Sorry about that.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102973

Answer (score 4):

If $C$ is an arbitrary category, then the "smallest cocomplete category containing $C$" is usually called the [free cocompletion](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/free+cocompletion) $\widehat{C}$ of $C$ and is defined to satisfy the following universal property: If $D$ is a cocomplete category, then the category of functors $C \to D$ is naturally equivalent to the category of cocontinuous functors $\widehat{C} \to D$. It can be constructed as follows: First consider the cocomplete category of presheaves on $C$, i.e. functors $C^{op} \to \mathsf{Set}$. By Yoneda the full subcategory of representable functors is equivalent to $C$. Now, take $\widehat{C}$ to be the closure of this full subcategory under small colimits.

Of course this can be applied to the category of schemes $\mathsf{Sch}$, but I don't know if $\widehat{\mathsf{Sch}}$ is of much use in algebraic geometry. Instead, one looks at full subcategories of $\widehat{\mathsf{Sch}}$, for example of sheaves with respect to some Grothendieck topology on $\mathsf{Sch}$ (e.g. Zariski, étale, fpqc, Nisnevich). An algebraic space is an étale sheaf on $\mathsf{Sch}$  which has a surjective étale morphism from a (functor represented by) scheme (and some condition on the diagonal). In contrast to the category of schemes, the category of algebraic spaces is closed under quotients by étale equivalence relations.

Comment: Can we define etale fundamental group of an algebraic space or of an element of  $\widehat{{\rm Sch}}$ ?

Comment: I don't know, but probably. Isn't this a completely different question?