# Is the push-forward of a quasi-coherent sheaf under open immersion still quasi-coherent?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, quasicoherent-sheaves

My question is related to this question: [When is the pushforward of a quasi-coherent sheaf quasi-coherent? Hartshorne proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109747/when-is-the-pushforward-of-a-quasi-coherent-sheaf-quasi-coherent-hartshorne-pro)

In Hartshorne page page 115 Proposition 5.8 it has been proved that if $X$ is noetherian or if $f: X\rightarrow Y$ is quasi-compact and separated then if $\mathcal{F}$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$, then $f_*\mathcal{F}$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf on $Y$.

Now let's consider an open immersion of schemes $i: U\rightarrow X$. In general  $i$ is not quasi-compact. But is it still true that if $\mathcal{F}$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf on $U$, then $f_*\mathcal{F}$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$?

Comment: For the most general versions of statements, you usually want to read EGA. I haven't checked, but I assume the result you are looking for is there.

Comment: There is a supposed counterexample in the 2nd ed. of EGA I (6.7.3), but according to the paper mentioned in my answer, this example contains a mistake.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to your question is **no** - i.e., if an open immersion $i \colon U \to X$ is not assumed to be quasi-compact, then it can happen that the direct image sheaf $i_* \mathcal{F}$ of a quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_U$-module $\mathcal{F}$ is not quasi-coherent. In fact, the [answer by Georges Elencwajg](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1109845/221584) to the very question you mentioned in your question contains a link to such a counterexample with $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{O}_U$. As Georges wrote, it is described (even including a proof) on page 36 of the following paper:

[A. Altman, R. Hoobler, S. Kleiman, *A note on the base change map for cohomology,* Compositio Math. **27** (1973), 25-38](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/CM/CM_1973__27_1/CM_1973__27_1_25_0/CM_1973__27_1_25_0.pdf)

On the other hand, the **most general positive result** I'm aware of is [[Stacks Project, Lemma 25.24.1](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01LC)]:

> For *quasi-compact and quasi-separated* $f$, the direct image sheaf functor $f_*$ maps quasi-coherent modules to quasi-coherent modules.

Note that this is a simulteaneous generalizations of both statements you quoted from Hartshorne.