# Is the Function field a quasicoherent coherent sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given a variety $X$, is the constant sheaf given by the function field $K=k(X)$ a quasicoherent sheaf?

I think so because to each affine open we assign K, and then for a localization $A \to A_f$ the map $K \otimes_A A_f \to K$ is an isomorphism.

But I don’t find this stated anywhere.

Comment: Your proof seems fine to me. Is there a context you have where you want to exploit this sheaf being coherent?

Comment: Well it has come up over the years a few times and I’ve never seen it stated. But recently I was reading Cutkosky’s Intro to algebraic geometry, he proves $K$ has no higher (meaning deg $\geq 1$) Cech cohomology, but he only states (Lemma 17.15) that sheaf cohomology in deg 1 vanishes. If $K$ is quasicoherent then since Cech is same as sheaf cohomology in this case i was wondering why he didn’t state that higher sheaf cohomology of K vanishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way you can think about this, is that one has a natural morphism $j: \operatorname{Spec} K \to X$ picking out the generic point and the sheaf in question is $j_*\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} K}$, which [is quasicoherent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109747/when-is-the-pushforward-of-a-quasi-coherent-sheaf-quasi-coherent-hartshorne-pro).